# Session screen - how to get session list

Tags: linux, session, debian

Hey i need get all session names for loop

```
root@xxx:/home/manager/scripts# screen -ls
There are screens on:
        5472.session1   (19.11.2013 11:36:48)   (Detached)
        5409.session2   (19.11.2013 11:36:38)   (Detached)
        5386.session3   (19.11.2013 11:36:27)   (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

any idea how i can get this names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
screen -ls | grep $'^\t' | while read name _rest ; do
    # Process $name
done
```